# Custom email header is only present after a console reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, actionmailer

I have been trying to set a global email header across all of our projects with the help of a gem of ours. Currently that gem is used to add a BCC email to all of our emails among other things. I added the code for the header to the method that adds the BCC email address.

The BCC address is added correctly throughout all of our projects so I know that this line of code is definitely run on startup.

This is the code of the gem in question.

```
  ActionMailer::Base.default "FOO" => 'BAR'
  bcc = message.bcc.to_a
  bcc << BCC_ADDRESS
  message.bcc bcc
```

The idea is that this header is present throughout all of our emails.

Now comes the interesting part and the steps I have taken to create the issue that I am having.

1. bundle the project with that new gem version
2. start up a rails console
3. send any random email
4. be disappointed that the header does not appear in the email. However the BCC address is properly displayed.
5. run `reload!`
6. send the email again
7. be confused as to why the header suddenly is present

I tried this in rails 3.2.22.5 (ruby 2.2.4) and rails 4.2.9. (ruby 2.4.1)
The header is not included when running specs however the BCC address is present there.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing these weird symptoms?

Answer (score 0):

Alright so the issue has to do with defaults being cashed for an email.
So the defaults are not rechecked when you resend the email.

To work around this I changed the way the gem handles to act in between each mail that I want to send by doing the following.

1. intercept the call for deliver_message
2. `mail.header[:'FOO'] = 'BAR'`